# can't delete data with axios from firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

---

**Problem:** I have a json file like this in Firebase:

And I have 11 cards in total. Each card has its own **delete** button. My goal is to delete it from the json file of the printed card when it is pressed the delete button.

The card is pressed. No trouble here. I just can't delete data in a function called deletePer. codes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Wrap from "../../Wrap/Wrap";
import CardStyle from '../cardStyle/cardStyle';
import axios from "axios";
import Api from "../axios-get";

class CreateCard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: []
    };
    this.readCards();
  };

  readCards = () => {
    //verileri dizi yoluyla aktarmaya çalışıyorum
    Api.get('/data.json').then(arr => {
      // Object.values(arr.data).map( a => console.log(a) )
      let a = Object.values(arr.data)
      console.log(a[0].fullName)
      Object.values(arr.data).map( val => this.setState({
        cards: [
          ...this.state.cards,
          {
            fullName: val.fullName,
            job: val.job
          }
        ]
      }))
      this.state.cards = [];
      }
    )
  }

  clickEvent = () => {
    var fullName = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    var job = document.getElementById("job").value;
    var cards = [
      ...this.state.cards,
      {
        fullName: fullName,
        job: job
      }
    ];

    var cardValue = {
      fullName: fullName,
      job: job
    };

    this.setState({cards:  cards});
    Api.post('/data.json',cardValue)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => alert(error));
      this.readCards();

  }

  deletePer = (personName) => {
    // console.log(personName);

    Api.get('/data.json').then(arr => {
      Object.values(arr.data).map( val => {
        if(personName === val.fullName){
          console.log(val.fullName);
          axios.delete("/data.json",{
            data: {fullName: personName}
          })
        }else{
          alert('Bir hata oluştu. Sayfayı yenileyiniz...')
        }
      })
    })


    // Api.get('/data.json', arr => {
    //   Object.values(arr.data).map(val => {
    //     if(personName === val.fullName){
    //       axios.delete('/data.json', 
    //         {data:{username: personName}
    //       });
    //     }else{
    //       alert("sorun oluştu")
    //     }
    //   })
    // })


  };


  render() {
    return (
      <Wrap>
        <input type="text" id="fullName" />
        <input type="text" id="job"/>
        <button onClick={this.clickEvent}>ADD PERSON</button>
        {/* <button onClick={this.readCards}>Verileri al</button> */}
        {this.state.cards.map( (card, index) => (
          <CardStyle 
                key = {index}
                fullName = {card.fullName}
                job = {card.job}
                clicked = {() => this.deletePer(card.fullName)}
                />
        ))}
      </Wrap>
    )
  }
}


export default CreateCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you're not specifying any id, but you're just passing `{data {fullName: personName}}`.

It should be:

```
Api.get('/data.json').then(arr => {
      Object.values(arr.data).map( val => {
        if(personName === val.fullName){
          console.log(val.fullName);
          axios.delete("/data.json",{
            data: {id: itemId}
          }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response)
          }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
          })
        }else{
          alert('Bir hata oluştu. Sayfayı yenileyiniz...')
        }
      })
    })
```